# listings and keywords in the index

Tags: listings, indexing

The `listings` package allows to index the appearance of keywords in a listing, for example similar to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language   = [LaTeX]TeX,
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  moretexcs  = [2]{LaTeX},
  index      = [2][texcs2],
  indexstyle = [2]\cmdidx
}
\newcommand*\cmdappearance[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}
\newcommand*\cmdidx[1]{\index{#1@\cmdappearance{#1}}}
\newcommand*\cmd[1]{\cmdappearance{#1}\cmdidx{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
 \LaTeX{} and \LaTeX-code
\end{lstlisting}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The PDF of this example looks as expected but it is not, really, as a look in `\jobname.ilg` and `\jobname.idx` shows:

`\jobname.ilg`:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2012] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file test.idx....
!! Input index error (file = test.idx, line = 2):
   -- Extra `@' at position 31 of first argument.
done (1 entries accepted, 1 rejected).
Sorting entries...done (0 comparisons).
Generating output file test.ind....done (5 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in test.ind.
Transcript written in test.ilg.
```

`\jobname.idx`:

```
\indexentry{LaTeX@\texttt  {\textbackslash LaTeX}}{1}
\indexentry{LaTeX\unhbox \voidb@x \kern \z@ @\texttt  {\textbackslash LaTeX\unhbox \voidb@x \kern \z@ }}{1}
```

---

This is no problem for the MWE but the second entry would be lost if it were on a different page. The `\LaTeX-` part of the listing seems to have an expanded version of `\textcompwordmark` inserted after the keyword as opposed to the `\LaTeX{}` part which got the expected entry. The inserted command apparently is

```
\@namedef{\@lst @um@}{\leavevmode\kern\z@}
```

(line 990 of `listings.sty`) which a redefinition of this command into

```
\@namedef{\@lst @um@}{\textcompwordmark}
```

shows. The `\jobname.idx` file then is

```
\indexentry{LaTeX@\texttt  {\textbackslash LaTeX}}{1}
\indexentry{LaTeX\textcompwordmark @\texttt  {\textbackslash LaTeX\textcompwordmark }}{1}
```

which is correctly parsed by `makeindex` but gives two distinct entries for `\LaTeX` in the index. (IMHO a worse case than the first.)

---

Providing an empty definition

```
\@namedef{\@lst @um@}{}
```

gives the correct `\jobname.idx`

```
\indexentry{LaTeX@\texttt  {\textbackslash LaTeX}}{1}
\indexentry{LaTeX@\texttt  {\textbackslash LaTeX}}{1}
```

and no apparent issues seem to arise. I wonder, though, how safe it is. I traced the `\@lst @um@` to the command `\lst@CCECUse@` (line 1021 of `listings.sty`) which seems to have to do with `listings` `extendedchars` option (it is finally used in `\lst@DefEC`, line 998) but I'm lost there and don't really understand what the commands are for. My guess is that

```
\@namedef{\@lst @um@}{\leavevmode\kern\z@}
```

is some kind of precaution/safety net (but against what?) and since I'm getting apparently no issues in my real use case with currently about 150 listings the question is more out of curiosity: can something (and what) go wrong if I define

```
\@namedef{\@lst @um@}{}
```

Comment: `\leavevmode` is a precaution against finding `\hbox` when in vertical mode. Suppose `-` does `\hbox{-}` in order to avoid line breaks; then a line starting `-` will do damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find `\textcompwordmark` a good idea, since it will enter horizontal mode exactly as `\leavevmode` does.

However, you can trick `\index` into not seeing the offending token:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\cmdidx[1]{%
  \begingroup\let\lst@nolig\@empty
  \index{#1@\cmdappearance{#1}}\endgroup}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\cmdappearance[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}
\newcommand*\cmd[1]{\cmdappearance{#1}\cmdidx{#1}}
```

This produces the following `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{LaTeX@\texttt  {\textbackslash LaTeX}}{1}
\indexentry{LaTeX@\texttt  {\textbackslash LaTeX}}{1}
```

Comment: That seems like a good solution. The precaution you mentioned in the comment also makes sense - I guess I have been lucky